# elevatedButtonTheme's textStyle property does not change text color in ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter

I define a `textStyle` for the `elevatedButtonTheme`

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xff64ffda)),
    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
  ),
),
```

But it does not change `ElevatedButton` text color, what is wrong with it?

Should it work the way I describeb?

```
child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: _submit,
    child: Padding(
      child: Text(
        AppLocalizations.key(context, 'save'),
      ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: show all the code, you must fail to properly update the theme. You use Theme widget  ?

Comment: @Jscti nothing special with ElevatedButton and elevatedButtonTheme defined in `darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation, we can see there about `textStyle`

> The color of the [textStyle] is typically not used directly, the [`foregroundColor`] is used instead.

And for `foregroundColor`

> This color is typically used instead of the color of the [`textStyle`]. All of the components that compute defaults from [`ButtonStyle`] values compute a default [`foregroundColor`] and use that instead of the [`textStyle`]'s color.

There for to change text color on button use `foregroundColor`

More about [ButtonStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html)